# jqgrid - i want to add dynamic List<T> to jsondata or any datatype

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, linq, jqgrid

I want my program to be able to see some words by country.
So, there are multiple choices in the search options to select countries, which are reflected dynamically in jqgrid. In the DB, the query works well and I get a list of it properly.
However, I want to pass these lists to jqgrid with jsondata or some datatype, but I do not know what to do. It's my code.

```
public class Search
{
    public List<String> languageGroup;
    public string stringID;
    public string category;
    public string product;

    public List<Search> DoSearchWord(........)
}

public JsonResult SearchDataGrid(string[] targetLang,string[] products, string search_word, string baseLang){
    Search search = new Search(); 
        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = 1,
            page = 1,
            records = search.DoSearchWord(search_word,baseLang,targetLang,products).ToList().Count,
            rows = (
                from v_search in search.DoSearchWord(search_word,baseLang, targetLang, products).ToList()
                select new
                {
                    cell = new string[] {   
                        //i want to add dynamic generic data
                        //this section,can`t use loop statement
                        //how can i get length of dynamic generic
                        v_search.languageGroup[0].ToString(),
                        v_search.languageGroup[1].ToString(),
                        v_search.languageGroup[2].ToString(),
                        //i dont want to do this
                        v_search.stringID.ToString(),
                        v_search.product.ToString(),
                     }
                }).ToArray()
        };
        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);}`
```

please, help me